# get XY of object in wpf for this situation?

Tags: wpf, canvas, transform

I have a `Canvas` with two or more objects. 
Now, I put these objects in a new `Canvas` placed in the previous `Canvas`. Then, I rotate it.

Now, I want to know how to get the positions of the objects in the new `Canvas`, as though there were no new canvas.

[image: Image1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following extension method to get the location of one `UIElement` with respect to another:

```
  public static class ExtensionMethods
  {
    public static Point GetRelativePosition(this UIElement element, UIElement other)
    {
      return element.TransformToVisual(other)
                    .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    }
  }
```